# Check if widget exists in tkinter before deleting it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a dropdown menu to create several widgets. I would like to check whether the widget exists (from a previous selection on the dropdown menu) before deleting it. I am using the following code:

```
self.ndim_options, self.ndim_options_var = self.DropdownMenuCommand(("1","2","3"),'-',"Number of indirect dimensions","-")

def DropdownMenuCommand(self,options,status,name,row):

    if row == "-":
      row = self.row

    optionLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, bg='turquoise')
    optionLabel["text"] = name
    optionLabel.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='w')
    var = tk.StringVar(self)
    var.set(status)
    w = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, var, *options, command = self.setdimensionproperties)
    w.config(bg = 'paleturquoise')
    w["menu"].config(bg = 'paleturquoise')
    w.grid(row=row, column=1)
    self.row += 1
    return w, var

def setdimensionproperties(self,val):
    row = self.RowEnd

    if val == "3":  #Set parameters for a 4D (3 indirect dimensions)

      #Remove any existing weighting functions
      if self.weightingFuncNameDim2.winfo_exists():
        self.weightingFuncNameDim2.grid_remove()

      self.weightingFuncNameDim2, self.weightingFuncNameDim2_var = self.DropdownMenu(("sinebell","gaussian", "sinebell2"),'-', "Weighting function dimension 2",row)
```

However, if the widget hasn't been created, I get an Attribute error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3141, in __call__
    self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
  File "test.py", line 224, in setdimensionproperties
    if self.weightingFuncNameDim2.winfo_exists():
AttributeError: Window instance has no attribute 'weightingFuncNameDim2'
```

Ideally I would like the if statement to return `1` if the widget exists and `0` if it doesn't, which was what I thought `.winfo_exists()` did. How can I get around this error? Also, how can I make sure that `.grid_remove` removes both the widget and the label?

Answer (score 5):

I see three possible solutions. In order of preference:

1. Add `self.weightingFuncNameDim2 = None` to your class' `__init__` method, and change your `if` condition to `if self.weightingFuncNameDim2 is not None and self.weightingFuncNameDim2.winfo_exists():`
2. Change your condition to `if hasattr(self, "weightingFuncNameDim2") and self.weightingFuncNameDim2.winfo_exists():`
3. Put your `if` block inside a try-except block that catches and ignores AttributeErrors.

Comment: I don't have any ideas for "how can I make sure that .grid_remove removes both the widget and the label?", but I figured you'd prefer to have half an answer than no answer. (in the future, it may be better to make separate posts for sufficiently different questions, so answerers don't have to worry about this dilemma)

Answer (score 4):

> ...However, if the widget hasn't been created, I get an Attribute error:

The best solution is to make sure your class always has the attribute, even if the widget doesn't exist. Set it to `None`, and then reset it when you create the widget. Then your conditional becomes:

```
  if self.weightingFuncNameDim2 is not None:
    self.weightingFuncNameDim2.grid_remove()
```

> how can I make sure that .grid_remove removes both the widget and the
>   label?

`grid_remove` will always only remove one widget from view. However, if that widget contains other widgets, those other widgets will also be removed from view.

Comment: Note that "if self.weightingFuncNameDim2 is not None:" is the same as "if self.weightingFuncNameDim2":

Comment: @CurlyJoe: that's not quite true. In practice it's often good enough, but in my opinion, if you're wanting to explicitly check for a value of `None` you should explicitly check for a value of `None`, rather than taking a "truthy" shortcut. It can be a subtle difference, but you should always strive to make your code as crystal clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the second part of the question .grid_remove() seems to leave the label in place. So in the example I gave, the dropdown menu is removed, but the text "Weighting function name dimension 2" remains.